# Meaning of word "nicy"

Tags: meaning, vocabulary, translation

Can you explain me the meaning of word "nicy"?

I'm newbie in english, and I've already tried google translate, but I'm not sure. Maybe there is some informal forms, or other ways of using this word.

Comment: You should include an example of the usage you've seen.  I've never seen "nicy" as a single word in the US, but sometimes "play nicy-nicy" (or "nicey-nicey") is used to mean being insincerely nice to someone.

Comment: Did you try dictionaries instead of Google Translate? (Why would you need Google Translate?)

Comment: Never heard of it.

Comment: I haven't got any example of usage, just single word. Google gave me such synonyms: sweetie, sweety, nicy, lollipop, candy, sugar-candy

Comment: ermanen, not yet, Do you know a good one?

Comment: @user127042: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/5459/new-close-reason-include-the-research

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OED does have an entry for *nicey-nicey* It sounds quintessentially late-nineteenth century to me. The Victorians had an obsession with *niceness*, perhaps following the brutal excesses of the early century, the industrial revolution etc. It was the age of emergence of the bourgeoisie, good manners and politeness.

> Pronunciation:   Brit.  /ˈnʌɪsi/ , U.S.  /ˈnaɪsi/  Forms:  18– nicy,
>   19– nicey.
>
> Etymology:  < nice adj. + -y suffix1.
>
> colloq.  A. adj.
>
> Categories »
>        Nice. Also reduplicated for emphasis, as   nicey-nicey adj. (also nicey-nice) .
>
> 1859   Trollope Bertrams I. vi. 120   The musty fusty people, and the
>   nicy spicy people, and the witty pretty people do severally assemble
>   and get together... Bertram's next-door neighbour was certainly of the
>   nicy spicy order.
>
> 1900   C. G. Leland Pidgin-Eng. Sing-song 64   Supposey die, my
>   catchee glave where wisee man command, All plopa China-fashion in he
>   nicey Gleen-Tea Land.
>
> 1922   J. Joyce Ulysses ii. xiii. [Nausicaa] 353   Go home to nicey
>   bread and milky and say night prayers with the kiddies.
>
> 1930   W. R. Burnett Iron Man vi. iv. 228   This little kid here with
>   all her nicey-nice talk.
>
> 1943   Sir R. Acland in Hansard Commons 391 1968   When I was a little
>   boy..I used to walk from my home to a nicey-nicey school in my
>   nicey-nicey red and green hat.
>
> 1968   R. Hudson Grace is not Blue-eyed Blond (1972) ix. 144   It is
>   such a pity that religion has become nicey nice and prim and proper.
>
> 1994   Vibe Nov. 25/1   Her apparent contempt for AD and revelry..was
>   evident with insistent digs about their nicey-nicey character.
>
> (Hide quotations)
>
> B. n.
>
> Categories »
>        A nice person or thing; a treat.
>
> ?1870   It's Funny when you feel that Way (song lyrics)    I helped
>   her to the niceys. And I filled her glass with pride.
>
> 1879   C. M. Yonge Burnt Out viii. 132   Oh, you're a tell-tale-tit!
>   Catch me giving you nicies again!
>
> 1914   Conc. Oxf. Dict. Add.,   Nicy..(nursery), sweet, lollipop.
>
> 1959   Listener 3 Dec. 1008/1   Young nasties after lots of lolly, and
>   young nicies to foil them at last.
>
> 1990   Daily Tel. 21 Apr. (Weekend Suppl.) xvii/8,   Davies finds that
>   nasties are now far outnumbered by niceys.

Comment: Good refs.  This also evoked memories of the character Nicely Nicely in the play/movie _Guys and Dolls_.